# how to pass a json object from html form submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I have a logging page and I wanted to send the logging details in json format to the checkuser.php file which is a other page in the web site. 
checkUser.php file will create a new window.
 What is the best way to do this ? if possible please give me some example.

Comment: Can you please give us more details about what you are trying to do? It's hard to tell what the best way to do this is without any context.

Comment: I have a logging form. what I wanted is to pass the data in the form in json format. to a other web page. similar way to the form submit but in json format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#myform").submit(function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: "blabla.com/api",
        type: 'POST', 
        contentType: 'application/json', 
        data: JSON.stringify( { key: val } ) // <-------- HERE IS YOUR JSON
    }).done(function() {
        console.log('hooray!');
    });
});
```

Comment: If you use jquery why can't you write it like, `$("#myform").submit(function(){   });`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a login form as login.php with html form controls txtLogin and txtPassword and a Submit button. Once the user submits the form it would post data onto checkuser.php
You can write the following code that can push data in JSON format

```
$login = $_POST['txtLogin'];  
$password = $_POST['txtPassword'];

$userArray = array('login'=>$login,'password'=>$password);  
$json_array = json_encode($userArray);
```

Comment: what I want is to pass the logging data in json format to the checkuser.php  page

Comment: okay, you need to include a hidden element variable say hidArr on login.php form, and bind the controls [txtLogin, txtPassword] change events that can update values in hidArr and convert to json array; and pass over to other form